# Access Issues - Same Profile

Tags: apex, case

Two users U1 & U2 share the same profile.

U1 is able to edit Case object record.

U2 is unable to do the same.

Can someone throw some pointers as to where should I be looking ?

The following error is shown to U2 when trying to edit Case record.

```
statusCode:'INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY'
```

Comment: If you click on the sharing button on the account record, it should say what is giving U1 the access.

Answer (score 0):

Who owns the Account? Do both user have the same role?
It could be that one user is inheriting write access to the Case based upon the role hierarchy or the Account owner.